# Tetrahedrane Properties and Analogs

Tags: organic-chemistry

I took a look into some [tetrahedrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedrane) ($\ce{C4H4}$) analogs, platonic hydrocarbon, basically very strained tetrahedral geometry at every carbon.  I was wondering what will be the predicted delta H of formation for the tetra nitro analog tetranitrotetrahedrane?  What will be the predicted detonation velocity too?  Could there be modified analogs that are even more energetic?

Comment: Have you heard of hydrazine? It's the most relaxed compound with a $\ce{N-N}$ bond. Even for that, Wikipedia says: `Hydrazine is highly toxic and dangerously unstable unless handled in solution.` Considering that fact, $\ce{N-N}$ bond is too weak to form tetrahedrane molecules.

Comment: If you are still interested, here is that article about cubane: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp511756v.  And the article about nitrocubanes: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-4087(200203)27:1%3C1::AID-PREP1%3E3.0.CO;2-6/epdf

Comment: @pritt I know it's old comment, but OP's talking about tetranitro, not tetraaza compound.  Tetrahedral N4 is crazy, but tetranitro... *might* be possible (and very powerful).

Comment: Highly nitrated cage compounds are a subject of some research interest (at least for chemists who think the five fingers is a surplus) as Derek Lowe illustrates in his [Things i Won't Work With](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-hexanitrohexaazaisowurtzitane) column. Octanitrocubane is known.